# Custom post type pagination return 404 error

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

I have problem with CPT pagination.
I try to use:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args_event = array(
    'post_type' => 'cpt_wydarzenia',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'category_name' => 'wydarzenie',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'post_status' => array('future', 'publish'),
    'paged' => $paged
);
```

and:

```
echo paginate_links(
    array(
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        'total' => $event_post_query->max_num_pages,
        'prev_text' => '&laquo;',
        'next_text' => '&raquo;'
    )
);
```

I tried flush permalinks, change permalinks to different type and still have got `404 error` on every next one page.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I just have the same name for page and custom posty type

My page to display posts: page.pl/wydarzenia and custom post type have also name "wydarzenia". I just change url in page which display all custom posts.